# About TidHttp, mshtml, ActiveX, COMObj in Firemonkey (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, activex, mshtml, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

I was reviewing the following interesting article, ["Extract Links from HTML page using Delphi"](http://delphi.about.com/od/internetintranet/a/extract-links-from-a-html-page-using-delphi.htm), and I tested in Firemonkey and it's very useful, however this code uses objects from Mshtml, ActiveX, and COMObj, so my questions are:

1. do those objects above make less cross-platform for a Firemonkey project? if so, How could I get the same functionality using resources targeted for Firemonkey platform?
2. How I can emulate a little webbrowser in firemonkey?

Thanks in advance.

*Note*: ChromiumEmbedded object does't work for Firemonkey.

Comment: Your avatar looks familiar to me.

Comment: hahaha, really? we are surely brothers-in-myth.

Comment: Delphi Chromium Embedded works with Firemonkey, it is experimental, so you have to define the "FMX" compiler option and recompile the package. You need to get the latest source from SVN. The mac port is still progress in the chromium embedded project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MSHTML`, `ActiveX`, and `ComObj` are all Windows-specific, and therefore are not cross-platform in any way.

There are no cross-platform HTML viewers for FireMonkey yet, AFAIK (it's been asked at the Embarcadero Delphi forums). `TIdHTTP` is available for Win32, Win64, and OSX; it's not available yet for iOS - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439974/what-networking-components-are-available-for-firemonkey-ios-apps).