# HTML Viewer for FireMonkey

Tags: html, delphi, browser, view, firemonkey

Is there a `HTML Viewer` for `FireMonkey` like this (VCL): http://code.google.com/p/thtmlviewer/downloads/list? It will be great if it has a highlighting feature.

### Added

I found later:

[About TidHttp, mshtml, ActiveX, COMObj in Firemonkey (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535672/about-tidhttp-mshtml-activex-comobj-in-firemonkey-delphi)

https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=60670

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Chromium Embedded](http://code.google.com/p/delphichromiumembedded/).

Answer (score 2):

you can use TwebBrowser that under android is a wrap of chromium embded. it's also a native android control

Comment: Do you still recommend using TWebBrowser for this?