# Import VCL component to Firemonkey application

Tags: delphi, vcl, firemonkey, delphi-xe3

How can I use VCL components in FMX applicaion?

In dept, I want to create a VCL component that contains Shockwave ActiveX and load it into my firemonkey form.

Comment: Very unlikely that this can be done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535672/about-tidhttp-mshtml-activex-comobj-in-firemonkey-delphi and https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64063

Comment: See if [`MonkeyMixer`](http://delphi.org/2013/09/monkeymixer-updated-for-delphi-xe5/) can be used.

Answer (score 1):

RemObjects have extended their Hydra product to allow mixing of FireMonkey, VCL and .NET.

http://www.remobjects.com/hydra/hosts.aspx

But this product have expensive cost